# Using the unique factorization to find the anwer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use the unique factorization theorem to write the following
integers in standard factored form.
a. 1,176 b. 5,733 c. 3,675

The factorization theorem states that you need to break a number into x,y,z. My question is how do you know which numbers to use for a? Like how do you know that you are supposed to use $2^2*3*7^2$ ? I also know you are supposed to use prime numbers that cannot be broken up. Any suggestions, on how to derive the answers for the others?

Comment: Just divide. Note that a. is even, b. try to compute $5733 \mod 9$ & c. note that it ends in 5.

Comment: I see you start with 2 and you work yourself through all the prime numbers until you get to 7.

Comment: So 5733/3 =1991/3 =636/7 = 91/7 = 13/13 =1  So therefore $3^2 * 7^2 * 13$

Comment: The point of the theorem is that you can solve the problem any way you like, the order is not important. It is easy to spot even numbers and numbers divisible by 5. By summing the digits modulo 3 you can see if it is divisible by 3.